Cannot mount CIFS with Kerberos from Synology DSM 6 and 7 : mount error(22): Invalid argument
I'm trying to mount a CIFS share from a Synology DSM 7.0 :
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/ADN_Archives
$ echo $?
0
$ kinit myUser@myDomain.LAN
$ echo $?
0
$ sudo mount.cifs //myNAS.myDomain.lan/ADN_Archives/ /mnt/ADN_Archives/ --verbose -o user=myUser@myDomain.lan,vers=3,sec=krb5i
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=x.y.z.t,unc=\\myNAS.myDomain.lan,vers=3,sec=krb5i,user=myUser@myDomain.lan,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
$ echo $?
22
$ sudo mount.cifs -V
mount.cifs version: 6.11
$ man mount.cifs
-sh: man: command not found
$

Both machines are joined to the domain.
The same error occurs on DSM 6.2 with mount.cifs version: 5.5.
EDIT0 : The remote myNAS.myDomain.lan server is not a Synology.
Here is the result of the smbclient command :
$ mkdir ~/.cache
$ smbclient -k -U myUser@myDomain.lan //myNAS.myDomain.lan/ADN_Archives/
WARNING: The "ldap ssl ads" option is deprecated
/etc/samba/smb.reserved.conf not found
gensec_spnego_client_negTokenInit_step: gse_krb5: creating NEG_TOKEN_INIT for cifs/myNAS.myDomain.lan failed (next[(null)]): NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
cli_cm_open returned NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
$ echo $?
1
$ smbclient -V
Version 4.10.18
Synology Build 42184, Oct 15 2021 18:26:01
$

EDIT1 : It seems vers=3 is not recognized :
$ dmesg -T | grep -vw agetty | tail -1
[Tue Apr  9 12:27:23 2024] CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: 3
$

So I replaced vers=3 by vers=3.0, I get a different error :
$ sudo mount.cifs //myNAS.myDomain.lan/ADN_Archives/ /mnt/ADN_Archives/ --verbose -o user=myUser@myDomain.lan,vers=3.0,sec=krb5i
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=x.y.z.t,unc=\\myNAS.myDomain.lan,vers=3.0,sec=krb5i,user=myUser@myDomain.lan,pass=********
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
$ echo $?
95
$ dmesg -T | grep -vw agetty | tail -2
[Tue Apr  9 12:28:12 2024] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -95
[Tue Apr  9 12:28:12 2024] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
$

EDIT2: Trying with vers=3.11/3.02/2.1/1.0
$ sudo mount -t cifs //myNAS.myDomain.lan/ADN_Archives/ --verbose -o user=myUser@myDomain.lan,vers=3.11/3.02/2.1/1.0,sec=krb5 /mnt/ADN_Archives/
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=x.y.z.t,unc=\\myNAS.myDomain.lan\ADN_Archives,vers=3.11/3.02/2.1/1.0,sec=krb5,user=myUser@myDomain.lan,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
$ dmesg -T | grep -vw agetty | tail -2
[Tue Apr  9 18:02:36 2024] CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: 3.11/3.02/2.1/1.0
[Tue Apr  9 19:03:04 2024] CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: 3.11/3.02/2.1/1.0
$

EDIT3 : Both machines are joined to the domain, here is my kerberos ticket :
$ klist -fea
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1067
Default principal: myUser@myDomain.lan

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04/08/2024 18:22:54  04/08/2024 22:22:54  krbtgt/myDomain.lan@myDomain.lan
        renew until 04/08/2024 22:22:54, Flags: RIA
        Etype (skey, tkt): aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
        Addresses: (none)
$


What is the sense of using CIFS? Synology have quite good NFS protocol support, for linux NFS is (kind of) native protovol.

@RomeoNinov The remote server myNAS.myDomain.lan is using CIFS.

why did you switch the slashes unc=\?

@SebMa, what is the myNAS.myDomain.lan server. Is this a Synology?

Are you able to browse the share using CIFS+krb interactively? Like smbclient -k //myNAS.myDomain.lan/ADN_Archives. The command you have works fine for me in the same version (though I have to set user=myuser,cruid=myuser). Do you have samba-client installed and up to date? The "Invalid argument" error comes up specifically when it doesn't know the option name in -o name=value like if you had an extra comma or bad character

@Cpt.Whale Added EDIT0

@Cpt.Whale Also added EDIT1.

Are both machines joined to the samba/AD domain? You may need to kinit again before using smbclient, but that error looks like kerberos doesn't know what to do with that hostname - is it the correct FQDN? For EDIT1, can you just exclude vers=x to let it negotiate, or try vers=3.11/3.02/2.1/1.0? It looks like code 95 can indicate issues with token signing, so try using sec=krb5 instead of forcing

@Cpt.Whale Added EDIT2.

To clarify, 3.11,3.02,2.1,1.0 are each different versions to try. Success depends on which version the remote server is running. vers=3.0 should be good enough, so the issue is probably something else. If you run klist, do you see a ticket for CIFS?

@Cpt.Whale Added EDIT3.

On the fileserver's smb.conf, check whether you have security = user (default) or security = ads. It should be ads when on a domain, like https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7063188
